# undefined is not an object(evaluating 'this.props.componentId') error in react native

Tags: react-native, redux, wix-react-native-navigation

I'm getting

> undefined is not an object(evaluating 'this.props.componentId')

error in react native when using wix react native navigation in redux actions

```
Navigation.push(this.props.componentId, {
  component: {
    name: 'navigation.appartmento.Home',
    passProps: {
      text: 'Pushed screen'
    },
    options: {
      topBar: {
        title: {
          text: 'Sign up'
        },
        background:{
          color:'#FD9804'
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

It works well inside a component but not working inside a redux action

Comment: Please post the code where you are calling this function. Probably there is no props object

Comment: I'm calling the function inside an action,not in a component.How to call push function inside an action?

Comment: Publish the rest of the code. But this.props is nothing inside an action unless you are passing it as a parameter